# SerializeException : Attempting to deserialize an empty stream error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on implementing a Save System for an Inventory System in unity following Kryzarel's tutorial on Youtube.
Here is the code which accesses serialize and deserialize and other scripts related to save system.

FileReadWrite.cs

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

    public static class FileReadWrite
    {
        public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath , T objectToWrite)
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
            }
        }

        public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }


        }

    }
```

ItemSaveIO.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class ItemSaveIO
{
    private static readonly string baseSavePath;
    static ItemSaveIO()
    {
        baseSavePath = Application.persistentDataPath;
    }

    public static void SaveItems(ItemContainerSaveData items, string fileName)
    {
        FileReadWrite.WriteToBinaryFile(baseSavePath + "/" + fileName + ".dat", items);
    }

    public static ItemContainerSaveData LoadItems(string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = baseSavePath + "/" + fileName + ".dat";

        if(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return FileReadWrite.ReadFromBinaryFile<ItemContainerSaveData>(filePath);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in" + filePath);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

ItemSaveData.cs

```
    using System;


    [Serializable]
    public class ItemSlotSaveData
    {
        public string ItemID;

        public ItemSlotSaveData(string itemID)
        {
            ItemID = itemID;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ItemContainerSaveData
    {
        public ItemSlotSaveData[] SavedSlots;

        public ItemContainerSaveData(int numItems)
        {
            SavedSlots = new ItemSlotSaveData[numItems];
        }
    }
```

ItemSaveManager.cs

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class ItemSaveManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] ItemDatabase itemDatabase;

        private const string InventoryFileName = "Inventory";
        private const string EquipmentFileName = "Equipment";

        public void LoadInventory(Character character)
        {
            ItemContainerSaveData savedSlots = ItemSaveIO.LoadItems(InventoryFileName);
            if (savedSlots == null) return;

            character.Inventory.Clear();

            for(int i = 0; i < savedSlots.SavedSlots.Length; i++)
            {
                ItemSlot itemSlot = character.Inventory.ItemSlots[i];
                ItemSlotSaveData savedSlot = savedSlots.SavedSlots[i];

                if(savedSlot == null)
                { 
                    itemSlot.Item = null;

                }
                else
                {
                    itemSlot.Item = itemDatabase.GetItemCopy(savedSlot.ItemID);

                }
            }
        }

        public void LoadEquipment(Character character)
        {
            ItemContainerSaveData savedSlots = ItemSaveIO.LoadItems(EquipmentFileName);
            if (savedSlots == null) return;

            foreach (ItemSlotSaveData savedSlot in savedSlots.SavedSlots)
            {
                if(savedSlots == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }


                Item item = itemDatabase.GetItemCopy(savedSlot.ItemID);
                character.Inventory.AddItem(item);
                character.Equip((EquippableItem)item);
            }

        }

        public void SaveInventory(Character character)
        {
            SaveItems(character.Inventory.ItemSlots, InventoryFileName);
        }

        public void SaveEquipment(Character character)
        {
            SaveItems(character.EquipmentPanel.EquipmentSlots, EquipmentFileName);
        }

        private void SaveItems(IList<ItemSlot> itemSlots, string fileName)
        {
            var saveData = new ItemContainerSaveData(itemSlots.Count);

            for(int i = 0; i < saveData.SavedSlots.Length; i++)
            {
                ItemSlot itemSlot = itemSlots[i];

                if(itemSlot.Item == null)
                {
                    saveData.SavedSlots[i] = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    saveData.SavedSlots[i] = new ItemSlotSaveData(itemSlot.Item.ID);
                }
            }
            ItemSaveIO.SaveItems(saveData, fileName);
        }

    }
```

ItemDatabase.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif


[CreateAssetMenu]
public class ItemDatabase : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] Item[] items;

    public Item GetItemReference(string itemID)
    {
        foreach(Item item in items)
        {
            if(item.ID == itemID)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Item GetItemCopy(string itemID)
    {
        Item item = GetItemReference(itemID);
        if (item == null) return null;
        return item.GetCopy();
    }
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        LoadItems();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        EditorApplication.projectWindowChanged -= LoadItems;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        EditorApplication.projectWindowChanged -= LoadItems;
    }

    private void LoadItems()
    {
        items = FindAssetsByType<Item>("Assets");
    }

    public static T[] FindAssetsByType<T>(params string[] folders) where T : Object
    {
        string type = typeof(T).ToString().Replace("UnityEngine.", "");

        string[] guids;
        if (folders == null || folders.Length == 0)
        {
            guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:" + type);
        }
        else
        {
            guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:" + type, folders);
        }

        T[] assets = new T[guids.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
        {
            string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]);
            assets[i] = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(assetPath);
        }
        return assets;
    }
#endif
}
```

finally 2 statements in the Character script Awake() function,

```
 itemSaveManager.LoadEquipment(this);

 itemSaveManager.LoadInventory(this);
```

and 2 statements in the OnDestroy() function

```
    itemSaveManager.SaveEquipment(this);

    itemSaveManager.SaveInventory(this);
```

what could have gone wrong here?
Also,this is the exception :

```
SerializationException: Attempting to deserialize an empty stream.
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler, System.Boolean fCheck, System.Boolean isCrossAppDomain, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler, System.Boolean fCheck, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler, System.Boolean fCheck) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
FileReadWrite.ReadFromBinaryFile[T] (System.String filePath) (at Assets/Scripts/SaveFile/FileReadWrite.cs:20)
ItemSaveIO.LoadItems (System.String fileName) (at Assets/Scripts/SaveFile/ItemSaveIO.cs:22)
ItemSaveManager.LoadEquipment (Character character) (at Assets/Scripts/SaveFile/ItemSaveManager.cs:40)
Character.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Character.cs:62)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `FileMode` for your stream in your `ReadFromBinaryFile` method from `FileMode.Create` to `FileMode.Open`.

I'm guessing that when you call `ReadFromBinaryFile` using `FileMode.Create` you're wiping out the file that you created using `WriteToBinaryFile`, which is why you're getting an empty stream.

This is how it should look:

```
public static class FileReadWrite
{
    public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath , T objectToWrite)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
        }
    }

    public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried doing that but it showed the same exception.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace of your exception.  Include some line numbers in your code so that we can reference those to the line numbers indicated in your stack trace.

Comment: i have added the log detail .

Comment: Edit your question to show the fix you made to the FileMode setting.  Make sure it is exactly the same code as the code you're getting the exception with.

Comment: `WriteToBinaryFile` still needs to be `File.Create`.  Only change `ReadFromBinaryFile` to `File.Open`.

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. That change fixed it. Thank you so much Robert.